# Exists a way to verify is a string like 'Abr 21 2010 12:00AM' is datetime and after cast to date time?

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, casting, sql-server-2012

Hi I´m using sql server 2014 and I trying to parse this 'Abr 21 2010 12:00AM'  to date, Im tried something like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'Abr 21 2010 12:00AM' ,105)
```

and

```
SELECT CAST('Abr 21 2010 12:00AM' AS DATETIME)
```

If I try to verify is the format is date with this :

```
SELECT ISDATE('Abr 21 2010 12:00AM')
```

The output was : "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Greatings and thanks in advance.

Comment: [**`try_parse()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx) would work for this without having to change the `language` setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `SET LANGUAGE` command:

```
SET LANGUAGE  'Spanish';    
SELECT ISDATE('Abr 21 2010 12:00AM')
-- returns 1
```

[MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174398.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT ISDATE('Abr 21 2010 12:00AM')` returns `0`, which is SQL Server's way of saying "No, this is not a date."

`SELECT ISDATE('Apr 21 2010 12:00AM')` returns `1`, which means "Yes, this is a date." (I just switched the B to a P in the month name...)

Is it just a typo?

**Edit:**

Since you mentioned that this is probably a language based issue, I'll add here that you can use the `SET LANGUAGE` command to alter your database language, even temporarily.  (This has already been added as a [separate answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42463461/4651160).)  The syntax would look like this:

```
SET LANGUAGE 'Spanish';

SELECT ISDATE('Abr 21 2010 12:00AM'); -- Returns 1, indicating that this is a date

SET LANGUAGE 'English'; -- Changes the DB Language setting back to English

SELECT ISDATE('Abr 21 2010 12:00AM'); -- Returns 0, because the language is no longer appropriate
```

Comment: Yes I think it is just a typo, thanks for the answer.

Comment: I thinks this is happening because my database language, in Spanish you type Abril but in English is April

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time something like that happened.  If you're using English date formatting, then just make sure that you take that into account when dealing with dates.  Hope the answer helped.

Comment: Hate to mention this, but copying another answer into yours is not so good etiquette... At least point specifically to the answer you copy, as the "rules" dictate (but still bad etiquette, in my opinion).

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis Hey Giorgos.  I can remove it, if you want.  It wasn't my intention to copy anything, and I did say in the edit that a separate answer had already addressed that particular issue.  I certainly didn't intend to break etiquette, or to offend you.  That part of the answer is yours; would you like me to remove it?

Comment: If you find a way to point (with a hyperlink, I guess) to the answer I think it's better.

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis Done and done.  My apologies again if it seemed that I was trying to "steal" your answer; not my intention at all.  I even up-voted your answer before this whole interaction, and I will try to remember what you've said in all future posts.

Comment: Thanks, take care!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this in Sql Server 2012+ is with [**`try_parse()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx) using the optional culture parameter of `'es-US'` like so:

```
select try_parse('Abr 21 2010 12:00am' as datetime using 'es-US')
```

returns: `2010-04-21 00:00:00`

If the value can not be converted, it will return `null`. So you will not get errors on failed conversions, just remember to check for a value of `null` and handle failed conversions appropriately.

---

In Sql Server 2012 and up: each of these will return `null` when the conversion fails instead of an error.

- [**`try_convert(datatype,val)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx)
- [**`try_cast(val as datatype)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx)
- [**`try_parse(val as datatype [using culture])`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx)